# Acer Aspire 1360 Recovery CDs

Tags: acer-aspire

I have replaced a dead hard disk in an out of warranty Acer Apire 1360 laptop.

The two recovery CDs I have dont appear to be bootable, they just contain .hdd and .ghs (image?) files.
On the original broken hard drive there was a hidden partition which could be invoked by pressing alt+f10 when booting. You would then be prompted for the 2 recovery CDs to perform the restore.

Obviously the new hard drive does not contain the hidden Acer recovery partition.

This being the case, how do I go about restoring Win XP?

The 2 CDs are called Aspire 1360/1520 Serires Recovery CD Disk 1 of 2 and 2 of 2.
Am I missing a futher bootable recovery CD?

Can anyone confirm how many restore CDs originally came with the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

GHS files are disk images created with Symanect Ghost. their [contents can be viewed and extracted with Ghost Explorer](http://service1.symantec.com/support/on-technology.nsf/docid/2001110808002125?Open&src=w) (which could be available for free, not sure though). maybe one of them contains the windows installation source files (usually in a folder named **i386**), then you'll be able [create your own Windows Installation CD](http://www.howtohaven.com/system/createwindowssetupdisk.shtml).

you may also be able to restore your computer from the GHS files with Ghost Enterprise edition (ghost32.exe).

Comment: Hi Molly, sorry but I made a mistake when I said they were .IMG files. I've ammended my question. thanks for answering.

Comment: edited my post accordingly.

Comment: please note the differences between the various versions of Ghost: up to v8 & v11 = GOOD, anything else = BAD (entirely different software, formerly known as Quarterdeck's Drive Image)